# WSO2 ESB adding namespace to SOAP Envelope

Tags: soap, header, wso2, esb

I need to add a new Namespace to the SOAP Envelope. 
At the moment it's looking like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
```

But what I need is this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
```

Maybe you can give me the code for the header mediator.
WSO2 ESB Documantation isn't working at the moment. I get a Synthax error there....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the XSLT mediator with the source attribute having the period value for its xpath. This will make the full SOAP message be processed by the XSLT template instead of the payload only.

```
<xslt key="yourXsltTemplate" source=".">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using header mediator you can add soap headers not the namespace at envelope element AFAIK.
Anyway [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Header+Mediator) should work.Please check. To add a namespace in the middle of sequence, you could use xslt mediator

Comment: And how can I use XSLT for this? If I look at the XSLT Mediator Documentation I can only find how to change the body. This documentation is realy bad... there is no description how to change the envelope. Even if I look at this example [link](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Handling+HTTP-get+Requests+from+WSO2+ESB+and+Calling+an+External+Web+Service) it seems like you can only change the body, not the envelope.